# groupby and sum in service angular 2/4

Tags: angularjs, service, sum

I am having some difficulties to achieve some things. I hope you guys can help me with this one. The result of our API looks something like (not all fields are shown):

```
[{
    "code": "CU03241",
    "naam": "Test1",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 5,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse"

}, {
    "code": "CU03242",
    "naam": "Test2",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 2,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse"

}, {
    "code": "CU03243",
    "naam": "Test3",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 10,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse"

}, {

    "code": "CU03244",
    "naam": "Test4",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 0,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Hoofdfase"

}, {

    "code": "CU03245",
    "naam": "Test7",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 4,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "H",
    "fase_naam": "Hoofdfase"
}]
```

This result i need to change to the following all in my service in angular. So i need to do a groupby and some sums. (grouby on fase_id and a sum on virtualec and ec. An example how i want it.

```
 [{
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse",
    "sumEc": 22.5,
    "sumvirtualec": 17,
    "Eindresultaten": [{
        "code": "CU03241",
        "naam": "Test1",
        "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
        "resultaat": "5.9",
        "ec": 7.5,
        "virtualec": 5,
        "sbu": 210,
        "kleur": "black",
        "isvastgesteld": true,
        "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00"
    }, {
        "code": "CU03242",
        "naam": "Test2",
        "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
        "resultaat": "5.9",
        "ec": 7.5,
        "virtualec": 2,
        "sbu": 210,
        "kleur": "black",
        "isvastgesteld": true,
        "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00"
    }, {
        "code": "CU03243",
        "naam": "Test3",
        "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
        "resultaat": "5.9",
        "ec": 7.5,
        "virtualec": 10,
        "sbu": 210,
        "kleur": "black",
        "isvastgesteld": true,
        "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00"
    }]
}, {
    "fase_id": "H",
    "fase_naam": "Hoofdfase",
    "sumEc": 22.5,
    "sumvirtualec": 4,
    "Eindresultaten": [{
        "code": "CU03244",
        "naam": "Test4",
        "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
        "resultaat": "5.9",
        "ec": 7.5,
        "virtualec": 0,
        "sbu": 210,
        "kleur": "black",
        "isvastgesteld": true,
        "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00"
    }, {

        "code": "CU03245",
        "naam": "Test7",
        "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
        "resultaat": "5.9",
        "ec": 7.5,
        "virtualec": 4,
        "sbu": 210,
        "kleur": "black",
        "isvastgesteld": true,
        "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00"
    }]
}]
```

I thought i could accomplish this with RxJS or something but i can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: see my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest with do custom filters. This may help you.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope,$filter) { 
    $scope.data =[  
   {
    "code": "CU03241",
    "naam": "Test1",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 5,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse"

}, {
    "code": "CU03242",
    "naam": "Test2",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 2,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse"

}, {
    "code": "CU03243",
    "naam": "Test3",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 10,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse"

}, {

    "code": "CU03244",
    "naam": "Test4",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 0,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Hoofdfase"

}, {

    "code": "CU03245",
    "naam": "Test7",
    "resultaatnumeriek": 59,
    "resultaat": "5.9",
    "ec": 7.5,
    "virtualec": 4,
    "sbu": 210,
    "kleur": "black",
    "isvastgesteld": true,
    "vastgesteldop": "2011-03-14T00:00:00",
    "fase_id": "H",
    "fase_naam": "Hoofdfase"
}
];

$scope.mani = $filter('groupBy')($scope.data, 'fase_id');

$scope.H = {"fase_id": "H",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse",
    "sumEc": 22.5,
    "sumvirtualec": 17,"Eindresultaten":[]};
    $scope.P = {"fase_id": "P",
    "fase_naam": "Propedeuse",
    "sumEc": 22.5,
    "sumvirtualec": 17,"Eindresultaten":[]};
    

angular.forEach($scope.mani, function(value, key){
if(key == 'H'){
$scope.sum1 = $filter('sum')(value, 'virtualec');
$scope.sum2 = $filter('sum')(value, 'ec');
$scope.H.sumEc = $scope.sum1;
$scope.H.sumvirtualec = $scope.sum2;
$scope.H.Eindresultaten=$scope.mani.H;
}else{  
$scope.sum11 = $filter('sum')(value, 'virtualec');
$scope.sum12 = $filter('sum')(value, 'ec');
$scope.P.sumEc = $scope.sum11;
$scope.P.sumvirtualec = $scope.sum12;
$scope.P.Eindresultaten=$scope.mani.P;
}
});
 })
 .filter('groupBy', function () {
  var results={};
    return function (data, key) {
        if (!(data && key)) return;
        var result;
        if(!this.$id){
            result={};
        }else{
            var scopeId = this.$id;
            if(!results[scopeId]){
                results[scopeId]={};
                this.$on("$destroy", function() {
                    delete results[scopeId];
                });
            }
            result = results[scopeId];
        }

        for(var groupKey in result)
          result[groupKey].splice(0,result[groupKey].length);

        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (!result[data[i][key]])
                result[data[i][key]]=[];
            result[data[i][key]].push(data[i]);
        }

        var keys = Object.keys(result);
        for(var k=0; k<keys.length; k++){
          if(result[keys[k]].length===0)
            delete result[keys[k]];
        }
        return result;
    };
}).filter('sum', function() {
    return function(data, key) {
      if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
        return 0;
      var sum = 0;    
      angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
      });
      return sum;
    }

 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainController"><p style="color:#3f51b5">{{mani}}</p>
<ul ng-repeat="val in mani" style="color:#609008"><br> {{val}}
  <li ng-repeat="v in val">
    code:{{ v.code }}
  </li>
  sum of EC: {{ val | sum:'ec' }}<br> sum of Virtual EC:{{val |sum:'virtualec' }}
</ul>

<div style="color:#010101">Did in controller:- <br>

 sum of EC: {{sum1}} sum of Virtual EC: {{sum2}} <br>  sum of EC: {{sum11}} sum of Virtual EC: {{sum12}}
 <br>
 <br>
{{P}} <br><br>{{H}}
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```